# AWS : The config profile (MyName) could not be found

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, credentials, aws-cli

Every time I want to config something with AWS I get the following error :

```
"The config profile (myname) could not be found"
```

like : aws configure

I'm using Python 3.4 and I want to use AWS CLI Keyring to encrypt my credentials..

Comment: See also: http://serverfault.com/questions/491124/aws-cli-cant-find-my-config-even-through-it-exists

Comment: This happened to me when AWS config file was not found since the user starting the service was a root user, when i started the service with ubuntu user it found the config, problem solved!

Comment: If using KUBECONFIG file with `env` of "AWS_PROFILE", then make sure it has the same profile as in `export AWS_PROFILE=same_profile` and in `aws configure set profile same_profile`.

Answer (score 173, accepted):

I think there is something missing from the AWS documentation in http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/setup-awscli.html, it did not mention that you should edit the file `~/.aws/config` to add your username profile. There are **two ways** to do this:

1. edit `~/.aws/config` **or**
2. `aws configure --profile "your username"`

Comment: The above other answers are useful but I think you're highlighting something important: if you go through the aws configure --profile protocols in the aws configure command line utility it will automatically update the .aws/configure file, which is easier.  At first I tried to edit it in VIM and couldn't get it right.

Comment: Also: I think you have to get the lambda and IAM default region to be the same to get that to work.  The region names in the pull-down are obscure, but the mapping of region name to region is here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html

Comment: My build also failed without the output=json or text specified.

Comment: Can you explain how to **create** a new profile with `aws configure` ? It seems that you need to bootstrap profile manually. Thanks.

Comment: I have solved my problem by editing both ~/.aws/config and ~/.aws/credentials

Comment: Note that, in the above, AWS considers home "~" to be %USERPROFILE% ; not %HOME%, which might be somewhere else altogether. This was extra confusing to me because, another tool (gimme-aws-creds) was putting AWS configuration files in %HOME%, which, of course, AWS could not find, giving the error message from the OP. Basically... if you get this message, maybe check you put your config in the right home.

Comment: Fixed by adding links in `/root/.aws/` to point to /home/ubuntu/.aws. If you process run as root you might also face this.

Answer (score 54):

I ran into this problem when I moved to a new machine, carrying with me my AWS_DEFAULT_PROFILE environment variable, but not my ~/.aws directory. I couldn't get any awscli commands to work until I unset that variable or properly configured the named profile. But even the `aws configure` command was broken, making things a bit tricky. Assuming you have a Unix-like shell handy:

1. To determine what AWS-specific variables you might have in your session: `env | grep AWS_`

   - if you don't see `AWS_DEFAULT_PROFILE` or `AWS_PROFILE` listed here, this answer is not applicable to you.
2. To temporarily remove the default profile: `unset AWS_DEFAULT_PROFILE` and/or `unset AWS_PROFILE`
3. To configure the profile in question: `aws --profile foo configure`
4. To reset the default profile variable: `exec $SHELL`
5. To test your new setup: `aws iam get-user`

Comment: Same issue with the `AWS_PROFILE` env var. Just `unset AWS_PROFILE` then execute the aws configure * commands.

Comment: I accidentally deleted my .aws folder. Your guide helped me.

Comment: Great answer. My problem was AWS_PROFILE set to something irrelevant. unset AWS_PROFILE fixed it!

Answer (score 11):

Working with profiles is little tricky. Documentation can be found at:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/topic/config-vars.html
(But you need to pay attention on env variables like AWS_PROFILE)

Using profile with aws cli requires a config file (default at `~/.aws/config` or set using `AWS_CONFIG_FILE`). 
A sample config file for reference:
`

```
[profile PROFILE_NAME]
 output=json
 region=us-west-1
 aws_access_key_id=foo
 aws_secret_access_key=bar
```

`

Env variable `AWS_PROFILE` informs AWS cli about the profile to use from AWS config. It is not an alternate of config file like `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID`/`AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` are for `~/.aws/credentials`.

Another interesting fact is if `AWS_PROFILE` is set and the `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` and `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` environment variables are set, then the credentials provided by `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` and `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` will override the credentials located in the profile provided by `AWS_PROFILE`.

Answer (score 10):

can you check your `config` file under `~/.aws/config`- you might have an invalid section called [myname], something like this (this is an example)

```
[default]
region=us-west-2
output=json

[myname]
region=us-east-1
output=text
```

Just remove the [myname] section (including all content for this profile) and you will be fine to run `aws` cli again

Comment: The example has syntax error. Removing the section works, but the error can be fixed by replacing `[myname]` with `[profile myname]`. 

It's a bit confusing that the credentials file does not require this prefix and that in the config file `default` profile does not require this prefix.

Answer (score 5):

In my case, I had the variable named "AWS_PROFILE" on Environment variables with an old value.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Use as follows

```
[profilename]
region=us-east-1
output=text
```

Example cmd

```
aws --profile myname CMD opts
```

Comment: i think this should be without "profile" in the square brackets?

Comment: @MarkusKöhler: Correct, had the same issue. Their docs on some places say otherwise: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/setup-awscli.html (probably outdated)

Answer (score 0):

Did you actually set up your specific user?  The walkthrough setup guide in AWS explains how to set a default user, and then how to set up additional users.  If you didn't complete the full setup, you'll just have a default block and your myName won't have been created..

Answer (score 0):

Was facing similar issue and found below link more helpful then the answers provided here. I guess this is due to the updates to AWS CLI since the answers are provided.

https://serverfault.com/questions/792937/the-config-profile-adminuser-could-not-be-found

Essentially it helps to create two different files (i.e. one for the general config related information and the second for the credentials related information).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are in the correct VirtualEnvironment. I updated PyCharm and for some reason had to point my project at my VE again. Opening the terminal, I was not in my VE when attempting zappa update (and got this error). Restarting PyCharm, all back to normal.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was using the Docker method for the AWS CLI tool, and I hadn't read the instructions far enough to realize that I had to make my credentials directory visible to the docker container.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/install-cliv2-docker.html

Instead of

`docker run --rm -it amazon/aws-cli:latest command args...`

I needed to do:

`docker run --rm -it -v ~/.aws:/root/.aws amazon/aws-cli:latest command args...`

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone is trying to do this on a headless server (CI runner in my case, adding an EKS cluster config to kubeconfig).

The reason I have to do this is because the runner is in a different AWS account to the EKS cluster in question (and the aws eks command looks in same account).

I do have a way of authenticating to the correct AWS account which populates ~/.aws/credentials with valid creds.

First I authenticate to populate ~/.aws/credentials
Then

```
cp ~/.aws/credentials ~/.aws/config
sed -i 's/profilename/profile profilename/g' ~/.aws/config
```

and then when I run following it works

```
aws eks update-kubeconfig --name cluster-name --profile profilename --region us-east-1
```

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issue while deploying the Flask application in Nginx and Gunicorn.

It may helpful for someone who faces the same issue as I was

My Case: ***generating rds AUTH Token using AWS credentials***

*In development mode it is working fine and able to fetch the AWS    Config from the **.aws** folder*

when I try to run it via **Nginx-Gunicorn Its gets failed**, Even though I gave all root permission to respective folders and services.

I have stored AccessKey and SecretKey in environment variables
and creating auth token by using those credentials

```
import boto3,os
S3_KEY=os.environ['aws_access_key']
S3_SECRET=os.environ['aws_secret_access_key']
def generate_iam_rds_token(server,region,port,user,S3_KEY,S3_SECRET):
   s3_conn = boto3.client('rds', region_name=region,
                       aws_access_key_id=S3_KEY,
                       aws_secret_access_key=S3_SECRET)
   pwd = s3_conn.generate_db_auth_token(server, port, user, Region=region)
   return pwd
#call the method to get a token
server='https://example.com'
region='ap-west-3'
port='port_number'
user='db_user_name'
pwd_token=generate_iam_rds_token(server,region,port,user,S3_KEY,S3_SECRET)

SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = 'postgresql+psycopg2://{user}:{pwd}@{host}:{port}/{db}'.format(user=user,host=host,port=port,db=db,pwd=pwd)
```

Note: In Ubuntu Os, Login as root user  by using `sudo -s` or respective user that you have configured in gunicorn
and
Do `aws configure`

Answer (score 0):

Please note the issue can happen if the aws config file is not found for the user which is starting the service.

For me the issue was the service was starting the root user so it was not able to find the AWS config file. I fixed it by making the service start from non root user sot hat AWS config could be found.

Answer (score 0):

If you use windows and write a config/credentials by Windows Note app, the app make a file with ".txt" extension. So, you could remove file extension. In my case, it worked.

Answer (score -2):

For me it was because I had my `.aws/config` file looking like this:

```
[profile myname]
aws_access_key_id = ....
aws_secret_access_key = ....
region=us-west-1
```

I think the reason is I based it off my `.aws/credentials` file, which requires having `[profile myname]` for Zappa and maybe some other aws/elastic beanstalk tools.

When I changed `config` to this it worked great:

```
[myname]
aws_access_key_id = ....
aws_secret_access_key = ....
region=us-west-1
```

Comment: The config files requires [profile XXX ] but the credentials file does not require the profile prefix.